# Do Various Update Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will update previous records to a corresponding MAX value.

Now I got the query figured out but what I want is to be able to run this update four times because the where clause will be based off of a substring of a field. Here's what is confusing me.

The substring will be checking on the following values - '01', '04', '012-', '042-'.

Is there a way I can do this without having the rewrite the update 4 times?

Here is my code-

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN


UPDATE Staging..lease
SET ls_origleaseamt = l.maxOrigLease
FROM 
(
    select MAX(ls_origleaseamt) AS [maxOrigLease]
    from Staging..lease
    where SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 2) = '04'
) l
WHERE SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,2) = '04'

UPDATE Staging..lease
SET ls_origleaseamt = l.maxOrigLease
FROM 
(
    select MAX(ls_origleaseamt) AS [maxOrigLease]
    from Staging..lease
    where SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '012-'
) l
WHERE SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,4) = '012-'

UPDATE Staging..lease
SET ls_origleaseamt = l.maxOrigLease
FROM 
(
    select MAX(ls_origleaseamt) AS [maxOrigLease]
    from Staging..lease
    where SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '042-'
) l
WHERE SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,4) = '042-'

COMMIT TRAN
```

I was thinking maybe a loop could do the trick? But It's the substring length changing that is confusing me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @AHiggins I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Are you sure your update statements are correct? The `04` update will also update the `042-` records. The `04` and `042-` records will have the same max. That is, it will be the max of the `04` and `042-` records combined. The same thing will happen for `01` and `012-` records but your code doesn't show an `01` update step.

Comment: Why don't you want to run 4 different updates?   4 simple updates that can use an index will probably run faster than 1 complicated update that has to do a table scan.

Comment: @Rabbit thank you so much for catching that I wasn't even thinking about that!

Comment: @TabAlleman I was thinking there might be a more efficient way than to writing 4 update statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE Staging..lease
SET ls_origleaseamt = l.maxOrigLease
FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '012-' THEN MAX(ls_origleaseamt) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4))
                WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '042-' THEN MAX(ls_origleaseamt) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4))
                WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,2) = '04' THEN MAX(ls_origleaseamt) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,2))
                ELSE ls_origleaseamt
            END AS maxOrigLease
        FROM Staging..lease
      ) l
WHERE SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,4) IN ('012-','042-')
OR SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,2) = '04'
```

There is some overlap between SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr,1,2) = '04' and SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '042-', and this will cause the '042-' to take precedence in the CASE statement as that appears to be what your original statement does.

Comment: Careful, the third WHEN condition includes the `042-` records in the MAX even though the `042-` records come first in the CASE. You should partition by a CASE statement.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. I actually didn't think about the precedence of the two.

Comment: @Rabbit - you're right that the third statement would actually encompass the second statement, but that's why I put them in that order.  If the data matches '042-', then the case statement will return that result without going to the '04' step.  I'd probably have to see a sample dataset to verify everything out, but I'm working within the constraints of the question and original code logic.

Comment: @morgb I understand the reason you chose that ordering, but it only works for the records where it starts with `042-`. The other `04` records that pull the max partitioning on the first 2 characters include the `042-` records. The case statement needs to go inside the partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MAX() OVER () syntax where you partition on a CASE statement.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ls_leasenbr VARCHAR(4), ls_origleaseamt INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('01', 2), ('012-', 1), ('04', 3), ('042-', 4)

SELECT
    *,
    MAX(ls_origleaseamt) OVER (PARTITION BY
        CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '012-' THEN '012-'
            WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 4) = '042-' THEN '042-'
            WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 2) = '01' THEN '01'
            WHEN SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 2) = '04' THEN '04'
            ELSE NULL   
        END
    ) AS maxOrigLease
FROM @t
WHERE SUBSTRING(ls_leasenbr, 1, 2) IN ('01', '04')
```

I added in an `01` case because you said you had one of those even though you didn't include it in your SQL.

I also feel like I should point out that you would need to run your updates every time you insert new records or update existing records to make sure everything stays in sync. It might be easier for you if you just created a view that returned the MAX when you need it.